Model ID not automatically generated in Entity Framework inheritance
I have two classes and I am trying to get Table-per-concrete-type mapping strategy to work for my inheritance. My setup has these two classes:
    public abstract class DatabaseObject
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public bool IsVerwijderd { get; set; }
        public DateTime? VerwijderdDatum { get; set; }
    }

and
    public class DefinitieBehandelaar : DatabaseObject
    {
        public string Naam { get; set; } 
        public string Code { get; set; } 
    }

My DbContext has these settings for the OnModelCreating:
        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<DatabaseObject>().UseTpcMappingStrategy();
        }

In my migration file the code in the Up function looks like:
            migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
                name: "DefinitieBehandelaars",
                columns: table => new
                {
                    Id = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: false),
                    IsVerwijderd = table.Column<bool>(type: "tinyint(1)", nullable: false),
                    VerwijderdDatum = table.Column<DateTime>(type: "datetime(6)", nullable: true),
                    Naam = table.Column<string>(type: "longtext", nullable: false)
                        .Annotation("MySql:CharSet", "utf8mb4"),
                    Code = table.Column<string>(type: "longtext", nullable: false)
                        .Annotation("MySql:CharSet", "utf8mb4")
                },
                constraints: table =>
                {
                    table.PrimaryKey("PK_DefinitieBehandelaars", x => x.Id);
                })
                .Annotation("MySql:CharSet", "utf8mb4");

and in my DataContextModelSnapshot looks like:
            modelBuilder.Entity("Database.DatabaseObject", b =>
                {
                    b.Property<int>("Id")
                        .ValueGeneratedOnAdd()
                        .HasColumnType("int");

                    MySqlPropertyBuilderExtensions.UseMySqlIdentityColumn(b.Property<int>("Id"));

                    b.Property<bool>("IsVerwijderd")
                        .HasColumnType("tinyint(1)");

                    b.Property<DateTime?>("VerwijderdDatum")
                        .HasColumnType("datetime(6)");

                    b.HasKey("Id");

                    b.ToTable((string)null);

                    b.UseTpcMappingStrategy();
                });

            modelBuilder.Entity("Backend.Database.Definitie.DefinitieBehandelaar", b =>
                {
                    b.HasBaseType("Database.DatabaseObject");

                    b.Property<string>("Code")
                        .IsRequired()
                        .HasColumnType("longtext");

                    b.Property<string>("Naam")
                        .IsRequired()
                        .HasColumnType("longtext");

                    b.ToTable("DefinitieBehandelaars");
                });

However, when I try to add DefinitieBehandelaars via the DbContext like so:
            dbContext.DefinitieBehandelaars.Add(new DefinitieBehandelaar { Naam = "Me", Code = "1"});
            dbContext.SaveChanges();

I keep receiving the error:
MySqlException: Field 'Id' doesn't have a default value

My project is on .NET 8.0.
I think I understand the error: for some reason, the Id from DatabaseObject is not being created as an AUTO_INCREMENT (see MySQL definition below), however I do not understand that because Id is marked as ValueGeneratedOnAdd in the DataContextModelSnapshot. Am I not doing TPC correctly, or what is going on here?
CREATE TABLE `definitiebehandelaars` (
  `Id` int NOT NULL,
  `IsVerwijderd` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `VerwijderdDatum` datetime(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Naam` longtext CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci NOT NULL,
  `Code` longtext CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci


@StevePy Could you explain why the magic strings are a major concern? I have only seen strings in my DataContextModelSnapshot  (and in examples online). I have tried [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)] but that unfortunately does not fix the issue.

Scratch that, this is all generated code so of course there will be the string values. Have you tried dropping the database and creating a new initial migration? From what I have read on Pomelo people have had issues if the schema was initially created without the auto-increment specified. For ID columns they recommend using just the [Key] attribute (or HasKey for fluent). With EF normally columns named "Id" are automatically treated as auto-increment PKs, though with MySQL/Pomelo that might not be the case. (https://github.com/PomeloFoundation/Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql/issues/300)
